# How can I get the binary search method to return false?

Tags: c#, binary-search

I am working on the binary search method in C# as an exercise, and it returns true if the number is in the list, but I cannot get it to return false if the number is not in the list.  I had thought about doing else if at the end with conditions that the UB = LB, but the SearchKey does not equal the MP.  Any suggestions?

```
static bool search(List<int> numbers, int searchKey)
    {
        int UB = numbers.Count - 1;
        int LB = 0;
        int MP = (UB + LB) / 2;

        bool done = false;
        do
        {
            if (numbers[MP] > searchKey)
            {
                UB = MP - 1;
                MP = (UB + LB) / 2;
            }
            else if (numbers[MP] < searchKey)
            {
                LB = MP + 1;
                MP = (UB + LB) / 2;
            }
            else if (numbers[MP] == searchKey)
            {
                done = true;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                done = true;
                return false;
            }
        } while (!done);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: the `else` block is never executed, at least one of the three if conditions will always be met

Comment: `bool done = false;`  put it inside do while

Comment: add this condition in your while loop `while (!done && LB < UB);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this condition in your while loop `while (!done && LB < UB);`

It runs Infinite time when no item is search

Comment: Thanks!  Works great. :)